# Split One table into Two in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to break one table (structure built by someone else but I need the data it contains thousands of records) into two new tables I created.

Table Name: **Customers_Info (Old Table)**

**FullName        Telephone        Address**

Adam Johnson  01555777          Michigan

John Smith        01222333          New York

John Smith        01222333          New Jersey

Lara Thomas    01888999          New Mexico

---

The above is the old table. Now I created two tables to hold the data, one table for customers with a default address, and the other table to hold additional addresses. In the shown example I need 3 persons to be listed in the Customers table, and the address of "John Smith" (the second one New Jersey) to be listed in the Addresses table.
The common field to look at here is "Telephone" and it's unique for every customer.

Here's how the result should be display.

Table Name: **Customers (New Table)**

**CustomerID       FullName        Telephone        Default_Address**

1                          Adam Johnson  01555777          Michigan

2                          John Smith        01222333          New York

3                          Lara Thomas    01888999          New Mexico

---

Table Name: **Addresses (New Table)**

**AddressID        CustomerID        Address**

1                         2                          New Jersey

---

Of course it was easy to copy all data into the new Customers table, but what I'm stuck at now, is how to remove the duplicates from Customers and insert them into the Addresses table with the Customer ID and Address only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try with below code and let me know the comments/results.

```
CREATE TABLE [Customers_Info]
(
    FullName        VARCHAR(50)
    ,Telephone      VARCHAR(50)
    ,Address        VARCHAR(50)
)

GO

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CustomerID          INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,FullName           VARCHAR(50)
    ,Telephone          VARCHAR(50)
    ,Default_Address    VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Customers
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CustomerID);
GO

CREATE TABLE Addresses 
(
AddressID       INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,CustomerID     INT
,[Address]      VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Addresses ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Addresses
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AddressID);
GO

ALTER TABLE Addresses ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID_Addresses_Customers FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Customers(CustomerID);
GO

INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Adam Johnson',  '01555777',  'Michigan')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('John Smith'  ,  '01222333',  'New York')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('John Smith'  ,  '01222333',  'New Jersey')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Lara Thomas' ,  '01888999',  'New Mexico')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Lara Thomas' ,  '01888999',  'New Mexico1')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Lara Thomas' ,  '01888999',  'New Mexico2')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Adam Johnson',  '01555777',  'Michigan1')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Adam Johnson',  '01555777A',  'Michigan')
INSERT INTO [Customers_Info] VALUES ('Adam Johnson',  '01555777A',  'Michigan2')
GO
SELECT * FROM [Customers_Info]

--DELETE FROM Customers
--TRUNCATE TABLE Addresses

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;WITH a as
(
SELECT FullName,Telephone,[Address],
rn = row_number() over (partition by FullName, Telephone order by FullName)
FROM [Customers_Info]
)

INSERT INTO Customers SELECT 
FullName,Telephone,[Address] from a where rn = 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;WITH b as
(
SELECT FullName,Telephone,[Address],
rn = row_number() over (partition by FullName, Telephone order by FullName)
FROM [Customers_Info]
)

INSERT INTO Addresses SELECT CI.CustomerID,b.[Address] FROM Customers CI 
INNER JOIN b ON b.FullName=CI.FullName AND b.Telephone=CI.Telephone
WHERE b.rn>1


SELECT * FROM Customers
SELECT * FROM Addresses

DROP TABLE [Customers_Info]
GO
DROP TABLE Addresses
GO
DROP TABLE Customers
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more normalized if you broke it up into one more table for three total tables.  Have the Customers table that has only customer data, have the Address table (which you could possibly rename to State) that has only the Address, then a CustomerAddress table that has both keys to each of those tables as Foreign Keys.

I will start you off to begin:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (FullName, Telephone)
SELECT DISTINCT FullName, Telephone
FROM Customers_Info
```

You would do the same for Address.  For the 3rd table, you would perform the lookups like this:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerAddress (CustomerID, AddressID)
SELECT C.CustomerID, A.AddressID
FROM Customers_Info CI
INNER JOIN Customers C
ON CI.Telephone = C.Telephone
INNER JOIN Address A
ON CI.Address = A.Address
```

Comment: well that's not a problem, but my problem is how can I get the data from the initial table and distribute it to the other two (or three) tables.

Comment: You would extract out all duplicates from the old table and load them into their respective tables.  Then using the old table as your source, insert into the 3rd table (the one with the foreign keys) the lookups from the 2 base tables.

Comment: Yes, I need the query to extract the duplicates and insert them into the other table. How can I do that?